# iPhone checklist app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, checkbox

I am trying to create a simple app that displays a list of items with check boxes next to each item, then give the user to simply check each box. Nothing (aside from the checkbox image switching) needs to happen when the check box is touched.

Each checklist is a seperate NSDictionary contained in a single master NSDictionary. The checklist dictionary contains arrays for different sections of each checklist.

At the top of the view, the user selects which set (dictionary) of checklists they want to open then I want that checklist to display underneath the picker once a "select checklist" button is pressed.

Any ideas on the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is to use a `UITableView` with the `accessoryType` set to  `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` for the marked cells. You can find lots of tutorials on working with `UITableViews`, and it'll be very simple to do what you're describing. For changing the data set, a `UISegmentedControl` is probably the way to go (if you weren't planning on using that already).